# How should browser based muiltiplayer game state be syncronized using WebSockets and a Node.js backend?

Tags: html5, browser-based-games, node.js, websocket

I'm in the process of learning how to create browser based html5 games. I'd like to eventually be able to achieve a game with mechanics very similar to that of the game agar.io. I've been observing coding streams and doing a fair amount of reading on the subject of network latency, jitter, and buffering but I'm still having difficulty ironing out an appropriate aproach to coding a node.js implementation to handle these things. I'm not so much as interested in having a solution provided to me as learning how more expierenced developers code tick counts, frames, etc...

Thank you all very much for your time and I very much look forward to any input your willing to provide regarding the subject. :)

Comment: You might want to check out this article I wrote: "Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web" http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html

Comment: Thank you for your input Mr. Alinone. Lightstreamer sounds like an amazing product and your article is better than a lot of journals I've read. I gained some real insight on some of the issue's that are in close proximity to what I'm after. But I'm still hoping more people can add input to the conversation by discussing node.js specifics around a standard implementation method for a game state engine.. etc Thanks again and I will be learning from your accomplishments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js & *the event loop* :
 To prevent flooding the action queue by multiple users playing the same game, I would divide the MMO into game rooms or game regions / zones.
Dividing the game server into independent threads that could even run on independent machines.

A `login socket server` for handling new incoming clients
with a `db reader & writer process` for db queries  & updates
For each game room available a `zone socket server` (for communicating with clients that are interacting in that specific zone : action requests & action result emission)  
with a corresponding forked `zone manager process` 
(for validating requests & result generation)

Maybe you like some personal notes...
(maybe a chance for this model to be reviewed & evaluated by the opinions of other devs)

```
<client>        Socket.emit('login_request', {credentials}) 
<server>        Receive login request [send to db_rwp]
<db_rwp>        Validate login_request {credentials} :: if valid fetch client (user) data & insert entry in active_sessions db table
<server>        Evaluate user.region : prepare region for client (ipc between procs with the folowwing data) {user:'{userData}', secret:'%ha$h%', csid:'login_handshake'}
<region>        Store @ incomingClients['%ha$h%'] ) = '{userData}'
                Inform to login.server {action:'prepared', region:'region_id', csid:'login_handshake'}
<server>        Inform Database then client 
<db_rwp>        UPDATE sessions WHERE socket_id = login_handshake 
<server>        Now inform the client :: io.to(data.csid).emit('valid_login', user:'{userData}', region:{id:'region_id', port:'region_port', secret:'%ha$h%'})
<client>        Load region splash screen while socket disconnects from <server> and connects to <region> (server:region.port) 
<region>        On client connect, return a client probe (requesting the secret hash)
<client>        Client is probed, return a Socket.emit('region_snapshot_request', '%hash%');
<region>        if incomingClients['%ha$h%'] is found valid
                    return the snapshot to the incomingClient
                    notify the incomingClient to the activeClient[]
                    activeClient['region_handshake'] = incomingClients['%ha$h%']
                    then destroy the incomingClients['%ha$h%']
                    Inform to login.server {action:'completed', region:'region_id', old_csid:'login_handshake', csid:'region_handshake'}
<server>        Inform handshake changes to Database
<db_rwp>        UPDATE sessions SET socket_id=csid WHERE socket_id=old_csid
```

Here I gave an answer that contains a client model that will only render what the server emits.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/116531/52482